# Import XML to Excel with repeating elements

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing, xsd

I have the following schema:

```
<xs:element name="response">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="transaction" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id_number"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="first_name"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="last_name"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="email"/>
            <xs:element name="custom_field" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional"/>
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="action" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="amount"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="action_type"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="date"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I import an XML file following this schema, Excel lays out the data as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6LgP.png]

I would prefer the values map as the following instead:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf7kn.png]

Notice how the number of rows is dictated by the number of action elements and the custom_field elements are maps to separate columns rather than rows.

Does Excel have some built-in function to easily control this?

I have written VBA macros to loop through the elements of the XML file and map it how I want, but it's very processor intensive. I'm just looking to see if there is a better method than what I'm doing today.

Comment: Can you please explain me "with your words" (not with code of course) how the first tabel became the second one? I can't understand...are the splitted into several tabels based on the custom_field values?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry for not explaining. The custom_fields are transposed from separate rows into columns. I didn't know how to display a wide table, so I just split them into different screenshots.